# Problem in listings, colored split command

Tags: listings, color

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
alsoletter={\\},
morekeywords=[3]{\\mbox,},
literate={\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1} {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1},
}

\lstset{language=mytex}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=[3]{\color{green}},
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\mbox{}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
f\mbox{}f
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

How can I do green, second `\mbox`?

Note: @karlkoeller's answer image. There is one space f between \mbox{}f.

[image]

Comment: `alsoletter` makes ``\`` a letter. So to `listings` the string `f\mbox` is similar to, e.g., `fimbox` hence there's no intention at all of highlighting just “a part of a keyword”.

Comment: @Manuel, I understand.

Comment: @Özgür There is not any space in the output of my code. Anyway, see the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to highlight LaTeX commands is to use `texcsstyle` instead of `keywordstyle` and `moretexcs` instead of `morekeywords`.

In your case, `\mbox` is already listed as a LaTeX keyword, so you need first to undeclare it from the default list of keywords

```
deletetexcs={mbox}
```

and then to add it in the `3` list

```
moretexcs=[3]{part,mbox,chapter}
```

To highlight them as you wanted, add the option

```
texcsstyle=*[3]{\color{green}}
```

to your style (the asterisk tells `listings` to highlight `\` as well).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
deletetexcs={mbox},
moretexcs=[3]{part,mbox,chapter},
literate={\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1} {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1},
}

\lstset{language=mytex}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
texcsstyle=*[3]{\color{green}},
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\mbox{}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
f\mbox{}f
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you don't like the standard `listings` spacing, use the option `columns=fullflexible` in your `\lstset`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{mytex}[LaTeX]{TeX}{
deletetexcs={mbox},
moretexcs=[3]{part,mbox,chapter},
literate={\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1} {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1},
}

\lstset{language=mytex,columns=fullflexible}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
texcsstyle=*[3]{\color{green}},
}

\lstset{style=mystyle1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\mbox{}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
f\mbox{}f
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is one space f between \mbox{}f. Is there a solve? @karlkoeller.

Comment: @Özgür There isn't any space in the output of my code.

Comment: @karlkkoeller, add image in question.

Comment: @Özgür See the edit. I confirm that there is no space in the output, anyway.

Comment: Perfect working.