# Why isn't moretexcs working here in \lstset or \lstdefinestyle?

Tags: listings

I'm very puzzled by my failure to do something that seems very straightforward with the `listings` package, using the `moretexcs` key with `\lstset` or `\lstdefinestyle`.

In the following, I successfully use the key `moreemph`to add `A,B,C` to the first class (colored red) and `D,E,F` to the second key (colored blue).

But when I try the corresponding actions using the `moretexcs` key to add identifiers to `texcs` classes, none of them gets formatted appropriately (orange, violet, gray, for classes 1, 2, 3, respectively); instead they stay green (default `basicstyle`).

I've tried (a) using `moretexcs` as a key to `\lstset` and (b) using `moretexcs` as a key to `\lstdefinestyle` to define the style `mystyle` and then invoke that style with `\lstset`. Neither is working.

At a minimum, I know that `listings` knows that this is LaTeX and that the first class of `texcs` is colored orange, because `\newcommand` is properly recognized as a control sequence and formatted with the correct color.

My syntax looks (to me) just like that used successfully in [karlkoeller's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229837/7922) to "[Problem in listings, colored split command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229809/problem-in-listings-colored-split-command/229837#229837)."

I've used `moretexcs` before, so I'm doubly puzzled that I haven't been able to figure this out.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX},%
    basicstyle={\color{green}\ttfamily},%
    emphstyle=\color{red},%
    emphstyle=[2]\color{blue},%
    texcsstyle=*\color{orange},%
    texcsstyle=*[2]\color{violet},%
    texcsstyle=*[3]\color{gray}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\\Pre-population
\begin{lstlisting}
\newcommand
A B C D E F G a b c d e f g
\end{lstlisting}
\lstset{moreemph=[1]{A,B,C}}
\lstset{moreemph=[2]{D,E,F}}
\lstset{moretexcs=[1]{a,b}}
\lstset{moretexcs=[2]{c,d}}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{moretexcs=[3]{e,f}}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\noindent\\Post-population
\begin{lstlisting}
\newcommand
A B C D E F G a b c d e f g
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: The `texcs` fields determine how TeX control sequences are typeset. Those start with a ``\`` in the code. But none of your examples use control sequences beside `\newcommand`. Try adding `\d` and `\e` in your examples to see the difference

Comment: Thanks! And… doh! I knew it would have to be something something on my part. I had just generalized something for `emph` to `texcs` without thinking through how to generalize my test for `texcs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `texcs` fields determine how control sequences are typeset in the listing. Those have to start with a `\`, which is why the solitary letters in your second example are not affected by the given styles. The effect is visible when you use actual control sequences in your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX},%
    basicstyle={\color{green}\ttfamily},%
    emphstyle=\color{red},%
    emphstyle=[2]\color{blue},%
    texcsstyle=*[1]\color{orange},%
    texcsstyle=*[2]\color{violet},%
    texcsstyle=*[3]\color{gray}%
}

\begin{document}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    moretexcs=[3]{f,g}
}
\lstset{
    moreemph=[1]{A,B,C},
    moreemph=[2]{D,E,F},
    moretexcs=[1]{a,b},
%    deletetexcs=[1]{c,d},
    moretexcs=[2]{c,d,e},
    moretexcs=[3]{f,g},
    style=mystyle
}
\begin{lstlisting}
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
\A \B \C \D \E \F \G \a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\c` and `\d` get `texcsstyle[1]` although they are defined by `moretexcs[2]`. This is because both are predefined in the `LaTeX` language through `moretexcs={...}` and thus are categorized as class 1. You can use `deletetexcs=[1]{c,d}` to remove them from that class to get the expected style:

[image]

Also note that in the second line of the output all uppercased macro names are highlighted as defined by the `moreemph` field. This is due to a bug, mentioned in the `listings` documentation:

> Bug: `texcs...` interferes with other keyword lists. If, for example, `emph` contains the word `foo`, then the control sequence `\foo` will show up in `emphstyle`.